# laravel 5.1 button visibility on auth::check

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

trying to make a button visible (ex. Admin Panel button) in my navbar on layout.blade.php file if Admin is logged in. how to write the code?

```
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/farmerPoint">Point List</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/crop">Crop List</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/SiteAdmin">Site Admin</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
thisbutton  ----------->  <li><a href="/AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a></li>
                          @if(Auth::guest())
                          <li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
                          @else
                          <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                          @endif
                       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/farmerPoint">Point List</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/crop">Crop List</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/SiteAdmin">Site Admin</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                          @if (Auth:check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                          <li><a href="/AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a></li>
                          @endif
                          @if(Auth::guest())
                          <li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
                          @else
                          <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                          @endif
                       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a boolean in your Users-table named is_admin you can do this.

```
  @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin)

  <li><a href="/AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a></li>

  @endif
```

Comment: okey, in my user table there is a column called user_type_id where, for admin the value is 1, for officers the value is 2 and for workers the value is 3

Comment: Well then its just @if(Auth::user()->user_type_id == 1 || if(Auth::user()->user_type_id == 2))

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can use blade function like
`@unles(Auth::check())
You are not Signed in
@endunless`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->is_admin == true)
        <li><a href="/AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a></li>
    @endif
@endif
```

If you were to do `@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin == true)` you will receive `trying to get property of non-object` for visitors.

You can also simplify it to the following:

```
@if(session()->has('admin')
    <li><a href="/AdminPanel">Admin Panel</a></li>
@endif
```

In this case in your login controller method you would apply the following:

```
if(Auth::user()->is_admin == true)
{
    session()->put('admin', true)
}
```